# Change some colors in listings package

Tags: listings

I use a program that is called CodeBloks in order to do .c files. It uses this kind of colors.  For istance.. how to obtain:
 - green after #
 - colour of the numebers = pink 
 - colour of '&', ',', '(' red like in figure?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can nearly do this, but there is a clash between changing / to red for division and using // to start comments. Perhaps someone more clever than me can suggest a fix. There are similar problems for /* … */ comments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  language=C,
  classoffset=0,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue!60!black},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{black!50}\itshape,
  morecomment=[l][\color{green!60!black}]{\#},
  literate=*{0}{{\textcolor{magenta}{0}}}{1}%
             {1}{{\textcolor{magenta}{1}}}{1}%
             {2}{{\textcolor{magenta}{2}}}{1}%
             {3}{{\textcolor{magenta}{3}}}{1}%
             {4}{{\textcolor{magenta}{4}}}{1}%
             {5}{{\textcolor{magenta}{5}}}{1}%
             {6}{{\textcolor{magenta}{6}}}{1}%
             {7}{{\textcolor{magenta}{7}}}{1}%
             {8}{{\textcolor{magenta}{8}}}{1}%
             {9}{{\textcolor{magenta}{9}}}{1}%
             {.0}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.0}}}{2}%
             {.1}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.1}}}{2}%
             {.2}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.2}}}{2}%
             {.3}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.3}}}{2}%
             {.4}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.4}}}{2}%
             {.5}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.5}}}{2}%
             {.6}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.6}}}{2}%
             {.7}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.7}}}{2}%
             {.8}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.8}}}{2}%
             {.9}{{\textcolor{magenta}{.9}}}{2}%
             {=}{{\textcolor{red}{=}}}{1}%
             {>}{{\textcolor{red}{>}}}{1}%
             {<}{{\textcolor{red}{<}}}{1}%
             {*}{{\textcolor{red}{*}}}{1}%
             %{/}{{\textcolor{red}{/}}}{1}% stuffs up comments
             {+}{{\textcolor{red}{+}}}{1}%
             {-}{{\textcolor{red}{-}}}{1}%
             {\%}{{\textcolor{red}{\%}}}{1}%
             {;}{{\textcolor{red}{;}}}{1}%
             {,}{{\textcolor{red}{,}}}{1}%
             {\&}{{\textcolor{red}{\&}}}{1}%
             {(}{{\textcolor{red}{(}}}{1}%
             {)}{{\textcolor{red}{)}}}{1}%
             {\{}{{\textcolor{red}{\{}}}{1}%
             {\}}{{\textcolor{red}{\}}}}{1}%
             ,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>
#define ZERO_FAHRENHEIT 32.0
#define SCALTURA 5.0f/9.0f

// il sequente programma converte una temperatura a FAHRENHEIT in CEL.

int main(void)
{
  float fahrenheit, celcius;

  printf("Immetti temperatura Fahrenheite:");
  scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);

  celcius=(fahrenheit-ZERO_FAHRENHEIT)*SCALATURA;

  printf("L'equivalente Celcius vale: %f", celcius);

  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Code output]

Comment: Can anyone else fix the / and /*...*/ problem? Can we consider // like just one symbol and use the #-solution you have suggested?